Word OLE Server Won't Release File
( Extending this Word 2007 OLE Locks File and Won't Close - similar issue )
I've got an RTF file and in my MFC application I'm using COleClientItem::CreateFromFile to create an OLE embedded object. Through the file association this starts MS Word with the -embedding flag to render the object. However, I can't seem to get it to stop once I'm done (preferred) or even close and release the file (sub-optimal, but OK). COleClientItem::Close and COleClientItem::Release don't seem to help.
Short of fully automating Word, is there anything else I can do to get it to release my RTF file? Even after closing my 'hosting' application, Word is still there, with the file locked.
